# JQuery Div popup overlay that stays within a form

Tags: jquery, html

I'm currently using a jquery popup overlay (https://github.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay) that works very well but I've noticed a site-breaking bug with it.

The popup is set within a form but the jquery code is relocating it to the top of the code, just underneath the opening body tag.

The standard html code:

```
<div id="my_popup2">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="blackbaroptions" >
    <tr>
      <td ><strong>Page Title:</strong></td>
      <td ><input type="text" name="content_titlepage" class="pageTitlelong" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['content_titlepage'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td ><strong> Description:</strong></td>
      <td ><input type="text" name="content_description" class="pageTitlelong" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['content_description'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Keywords:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="content_keywords" class="pageTitlelong" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['content_keywords'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><button class="my_popup2_close exturlclose" style="margin-top:5px;">Close</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

And the jquery that fires it:

```
$('#my_popup2').popup({
        vertical:'top',
        offsettop:60,
        transition: 'all 0.3s',
        autozindex: true,
        color:'#000'
    });
```

If I comment out the opening and closing div tags it submits to the form perfectly. But when it's running as before and I 'Inspect Element' in Chrome it's shifted it to the very top of the code.

So it's consequently not keeping it within the form and not submitting the data within it when the user clicks submit.

Does anyone know either how I can fix this or whether I can substitute it for one that doesn't shift the code around?

Comment: Tables for layout, tut tut

Comment: Try this one http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popup is placed where it is so that it can be absolutely positioned above all elements. This cannot be changed.

What you will need to do is hook to one of the events of the popup (probably `onclose` based on what you've said) and then transfer the values in the popups' inputs to hidden fields within the `form`. Something like this:

```
$('#my_popup2').popup({
    vertical:'top',
    offsettop:60,
    transition: 'all 0.3s',
    autozindex: true,
    color:'#000',
    onclose: function() {
        $('#hiddenPageTitleLong').val($('#my_popup .pageTitlelong').val());
    };
});
```

Comment: Amazingly, that's exactly what I'm doing right now. But thanks for explaining why it's doing it in the first place.

Comment: Definite markup for giving me the exact syntax for the onclose. I would have struggled with getting that exactly right.